# The Name Limit for the Local Computer Network Adapter Was Exceeded

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, network-share

I am facing issue with my windows server 2008r2 sp1 that every two or three days later i am unable to access active directory tools,symantec endpoint protection manager and stop file and printing service (there is no logon server available) i have run netst -a commant some connection showing waiting and close state and also stop internet browsing. After restart server everything working fine.

Please help what i can do.

Comment: Have you at least looked at, you know, web search? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319504

Comment: There is no registry string in windows server 2008 as mention in above link.

Answer (score 0):

If SEP is installed on local client, just make sure SEP firewall is not blocking any connection. Personally I have never heard about this issue.

To disable SEP go to Start --> Run --> smc -stop (To stop the SEP service )

Start --> Run --> smc -start (To Start the SEP service)

Comment: I have try but not working.